# PGError: ERROR: permission denied for relation (when using Heroku)

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, permissions

I've recently gone through the database migration process as outlined here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/migrating-from-shared-database-to-heroku-postgres

Now I'm seeing a number of errors in the logs like this:

PGError: ERROR: permission denied for relation

Any ideas on what I should do to fix it?

Comment: I had the same thing. I deleted rows in the DB on Heroku and had to wait a few minutes and then it allowed me to migrate the DB

Answer (score 170, accepted):

I had a similar problem but the root cause was that my app was pointing to the old dev database which had exceeded it's limit of 10,000 rows.

Although I created a new Basic db and backed everything up, the app was still pointing the old dev DB.

```
heroku pg:info
```

Check to see the rows: 10300/10000 (then you have a problem)

You will need to 
1) Create new DB with more rows (Basic or the "Production" ones -> Heroku seems to be forcing an upgrade to make more money errrrrr)
2) backup the old DB using pgbackups: `heroku pg:backups:capture SMALL_DB_NAME`
3) restore the backup to the new DB: `heroku pg:backups:restore BACKUP_ID BIG_DB_NAME` (see links below for more details)
4) PROMOTE the new DB to the primary for the app: `heroku pg:promote BIG_DB_NAME`

can always utilize:

> > `heroku maintenance:on`  (to disable the app while updating)

> > `heroku maintenance:off`

> > `heroku pg:info` (to check the status)

If this is the problem you may want to check out:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-starter-tier
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/migrating-from-shared-database-to-heroku-postgres

Comment: Thanks Ashton - running through all that again worked perfectly.

Comment: Mine says: Rows:        57845/10000 (Write access revoked)

Comment: Yes, well that would put you over the limit. Looks like you will have to upgrade, and I hope these instructions will help!

Comment: Instead of upgrading, I deleted some rows (as it is my test environment). Is there any action I need to do to recover write access in that case?

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger you have to wait about 30 minutes, according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/12710024/6678

Comment: Steps 2 and 3 can be done in one shot via `heroku pgbackups:transfer`. In the back end we dump the source DB and restore it on the target server side, which is faster so you'll experience a smaller downtime.

Comment: if you dont care about the data, you can log into heroku and reset the database. after that you will gain write access again..you will loose the data though.. i had this issue on a test server so the data wasnt of much value to me.

Comment: Maybe it's useful to mention that the command had changed from `heroku pgbackups:capture` to `heroku pg:backups:capture`. Notice the semicolon between `pg:backups`

Answer (score 11):

UPDATE: Ashton's answer nails it in this situation, which is very Heroku specific. If you found this from a search for PostgreSQL error messages or problems but are *not* using Heroku, please look for other questions more likely to apply to your situation.

---

At a guess, the PostgreSQL user ID you're connecting with is not the owner of your tables, and you haven't issued any explicit `GRANT` statements to give it access to them. Without seeing *exactly* what you ran when you migrated it's hard to say more - and Heroku hides many of the internals anyway.

Let's work out what the current situation is. Try connecting with `psql` and running:

```
\dp the_problem_table
```

and show the permisions reported. Also show the result of:

```
SHOW current_user;
```

run from `psql` and when run as an SQL query from inside your application.

Edit your question to add that information and *the full, exact text of the error message you get*.

Comment: Heroku doesn't allow lowlevel access to its db

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ ... and nothing here is "low level"

Comment: `psql` in that context lowlevel

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Then you're incorrect. You can connect directly to a Heroku database with `psql`. The easy way is `heroku pg:psql` but you can also use `psql` directly using the database connection string obtained from heroku.

Comment: Then you answer isn't full, and dont cover the question. Because it give not the answer on how to make access to psql on heroku.

Comment: `heroku pg:psql`. It's in the manual. It doesn't say how to install the `heroku` commands either, or to press enter at the end of each line.

Comment: The good approch to writing articles includes mentioning about manual or common things, either with just reference or short example. You can make answer better just by adding a short note to `pg:psql`.

Answer (score 11):

Steps based on Ashton's answer to upgrade from Dev (10k rows limit) to Basic (10M rows limit)

check db rows exceded limit

```
heroku pg:info
```

disable the app and workers to ensure no db changes during db upgrade

```
heroku maintenance:on
heroku ps:scale worker=0
```

if you don't have pgbackups

```
heroku addons:add pgbackups
```

backup database and get backup id

```
heroku pg:backups:capture
```

add db with web interface

1. login to https://addons.heroku.com
2. search "Heroku Postgres"
3. select plan and application
4. add it

view heroku config, you should see new db URL

```
heroku config --remote heroku
```

restore backup to new db

```
heroku pg:backups:restore BACKUP_ID NEW_DB_URL
```

change DATABASE_URL

```
heroku pg:promote NEW_DB_URL
```

enable the app and workers

```
heroku maintenance:off
heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

Comment: Maybe it's useful to mention that the command had changed from heroku `pgbackups:capture` to heroku `pg:backups:capture`. Notice the semicolon between `pg:backups`

Answer (score 7):

After deleting the extra rows, you won't get the insert privileges back immediately. In that case, delete the extra rows and just run `heroku pg:info` after that. This will refresh the privileges of your DB and you will get the access back in few minutes. Its not required to clone the existing DB into a new one and setting the new one as the DB of your app.

```
$ heroku pg:info

=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BRONZE_URL, DATABASE_URL
Plan:        Hobby-dev
Status:      Available
Connections: 3/20
PG Version:  9.3.6
Created:     2014-03-01 13:47 UTC
Data Size:   1.25 GB
Tables:      4
Rows:        2098/10000 (Write access revoked) - refreshing
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
Rollback:    Unsupported
Add-on:      grinning-busily-5587
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped.

More to add: I had to add param --app=APP_NAME, because DB is connected to specific application on my Heroku.

Answer (score 2):

I was in a situation where I exceeded row count limit.

This answer explained how to list number of rows in each table:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701711/heroku-row-count-incorrect](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/12701711/heroku-row-count-incorrect)

Very valuable to know.

You can get into the psql console through terminal, the connection settings are listed on heroku dashboard for your app!

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem on my Redmine application:

```
PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied for relation settings
: SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  WHERE "settings"."name" = 'plugin_redmine_wktime' LIMIT 1
```

My steps were:

1. I made a backup of old Redmine application and database.
2. I deployed a new version of Redmine - it worked perfectly
3. I restored old Redmine as a development server and I got an error
   when I tried to access the main webpage.

The cause of my problem was just in wrong username in old Redmine's config/database.yml