# Heroku Row Count Incorrect

Tags: heroku

I've been using heroku for one of my applications and it got shutdown today because the row count has exceeded 10,000 rows.

I don't understanding how this figure is arrived at though, as rails tells me I only have around 2000 records in the db.

Running a pg:info, I see the following:

```
Plan:        Dev
Status:      available
Connections: 1
PG Version:  9.1.5
Created:     2012-09-25 03:12 UTC
Data Size:   11.0 MB
Tables:      9
Rows:        15686/10000 (Write access revoked)
Fork/Follow: Unavailable
```

Can anyone explain to me how I seem to have 15,000 rows despite only have 2,000 records in the database?

Thanks!

Comment: the same happens for me although I've truncated a table 5 mins ago and restarted my app, It says "Write access revoked" with an incorrect number of lines.

Comment: UPDATE: after 30 mins `heroku pg:info` report the correct number of records.

Comment: Thanks! I would recommend too `heroku maintenance:on` update your tables or `TRUNCATE your_table` and then `heroku maintenance:off`. It worked perfect to me. [link] (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/maintenance-mode)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Rails alone is not enough. Heroku has a nice SQL console that you can access with:

```
heroku pg:psql YOUR_DB_URL
```

then you can write this query to obtain a rank of records per table:

```
SELECT schemaname,relname,n_live_tup 
  FROM pg_stat_user_tables 
  ORDER BY n_live_tup DESC;
```

If you need only the updated num. of rows, you can use

```
SELECT sum(n_live_tup) FROM pg_stat_user_tables;
```

Please note that you can have both the new dev plan db and the old SHARED one in your config (access it by `heroku pg:info`). You have to insert the correct db url, probably the one with a color.

Allow a 30 mins delay between any sql `truncate` and the `Rows` count to update.

BTW the web console on http://heroku.com in my case was updated with the correct num. during my sql queries. May be heroku toolbelt console updates, are slower.

Comment: Thank you - turns out the sessions database had a crazy amount of rows in it and I didn't turn this up via checking all my rails models.

Fantastic answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I contacted Heroku Support on this and they ran the following command to get my numbers...

```
$ heroku pg:info
```

Answer (score 0):

30 mins weren't enough for me, so I took a backup and restored the database. Then my app came back online.