# Do deleted SQL entries still take up space/rows?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, heroku

I'm developing an app through Django, where users can update specific entries using a RESTful interface. Since everything is posted through JSON, and the number of entries can stay the same, decrease, or increase everytime a user updates their entries, I thought the best way to handle this would be to delete all of the user's current entries, and re-add all the entries they submitted.

I'm using heroku to host the site, and for their hobby databases, they restrict by # of rows. Even for their standard Databases, they restrict based on size... I have noticed that when I delete objects in Django, the index will never reset, and I understand why, but does that mean that deleted rows still take up space/exist? I'm using PostgreSQL if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do deleted SQL entries still take up space/rows?

In PostgreSQL, yes, they still take up space for a while. So do the old versions of rows that you `UPDATE`d. After a while `VACUUM` comes up and marks the space as available for re-use, though it's still "in use" as far as the operating system is concerned. Then a while later a new row from an `INSERT` or a new version of an `UPDATE`d row gets written over the old, vacuum'd row.

You can `TRUNCATE` a table, causing all rows to be immediately purged, but that's an all-or-nothing thing.

Whether Heroku counts deleted rows or not depends on internals of how they implement their system, and is unrelated to whether they still take up space. If I had to guess I'd say "no", because on Heroku you don't control vacuum activity etc, so it'd be rather unfair to make you wait for their vacuum to get around to doing cleanup.

[Heroku has some documentation on the topic here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-database-tuning).

Comment: So how long is "a while" approximately?

Comment: Depends on autovacuum settings, table size, how busy the DB is, etc.

Comment: But will it be gone within say - 24 hours? What's a good maximum time to assume?

Comment: There is no maximum you can assume. If autovacuum isn't running, dead rows could stick around forever. If you want Heroku-specific details, then you may need to contact their support to find out how dead rows and bloat are accounted for. This post suggests that it's *live* rows (i.e. not deleted) that they count: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12701711/398670

Comment: When you run `heroku pg:info` a vacuum is triggered AFAIK.