# Heroku: PG::Error: ERROR: permission denied for relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

Every time when I try to save something into the database, I get this error message.
I saw that Heroku offer free PostgreSQL database for the first 10.000 records, above 10.000 records is needed to pay for the database.

Right now, in my database is like 60.000 records. How to fix that error/upgrade database?

Thank you in advance

Comment: -1 no research effort; this is widely discussed and well documented, including right on Heroku's site, and on SO with questions like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11930996/398670

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to use the PG Backups add-on to backup your database then migrate from your dev/basic plan to a production-grade (paid) plan.

The short of it:

- Provision new production grade Heroku Postgresql plan
- Put your app on maintenance mode to prevent new updates
- Capture the backup
- Restore to the upgraded database
- Promote new database to primary
- Reactivate your app

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrade-heroku-postgres-with-pgbackups

Answer (score 5):

You are over your limit. You need to [upgrade to a larger plan](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrade-heroku-postgres-with-pgbackups#upgrading-from-dev-to-basic), delete data, or live with having read-only access. Those are your only three options.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to upgrade your plan on heroku. To do that, go to [this](https://addons.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql) link.

[This](https://gist.github.com/3165360) is a very nice article where all the steps to migrate a DB on heroku to another plan are explained.

I have also faced this problem and fixed the problem smoothly with the help of the above tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Or :

Load a dump of you db locally. Clean this up. Put this dump on heroku.

Or :

Connect via psql or pgadmin to the remote database and clean this up.

*This answer isn't sponsored by Heroku*

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add my solution for posterity. I had the same issue where I was getting the error `:Heroku: PG::Error: ERROR: permission denied for relation"` event though I was only using `180/10000` rows of my DB. I did:

```
heroku restart
```

and this fixed the issue.

Comment: I had the same issue but first it was raising a `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied for table`, later I restarted dynos and it appeared `PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied for table` plus other similar errors `PG::UnableToSend: SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly`. After rebooting 2 times it worked.