# Outside form submission to rails app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, heroku

i send info from an outside form to my rails app on Heroku- it was running fine and now has suddenly stopped- not sure why [i did add unicorn and change to ruby 1.9.3 but i dont think these were the problem.]
i stripped down the code to just basics and it still stops the app.

any suggestions would be appreciated. thanks!

here is the outside form:

```
<form action="https://pacific-forest-7999.herokuapp.com/exams" method="post" \>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="">
</form>
```

i simplified the exams_controller.rb for the create action to:

```
def create
 @exam = Exam.new(params[:exam])

 respond_to do |format|
  if @exam.save
    format.html { redirect_to @exam, notice: 'Exam was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @exam, status: :created, location: @exam }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @exam.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

and here is some of the logs when it fails [tho i dont see exam controller actions listed there...]

```
» 11:20:47.516  2013-10-11 18:18:56.319768+00:00 app web.1     - - Started GET "/" for 184.73.237.85/ec2-184-73-237-85.compute-1.amazonaws.com at 2013-10-11 18:18:56 +0000
» 11:20:47.516  2013-10-11 18:18:56.323627+00:00 app web.1     - - Processing by PatientsController#index as */*
» 11:20:47.516  2013-10-11 18:18:56.331746+00:00 app web.1     - -   Rendered patients/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.2ms)
» 11:20:47.516  2013-10-11 18:18:56.333623+00:00 app web.1     - -   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
» 11:20:47.516  2013-10-11 18:18:56.341719+00:00 app web.1     - -   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
» 11:20:47.516  2013-10-11 18:18:56.342156+00:00 app web.1     - - Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 11.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
» 11:20:53.531  2013-10-11 18:20:53.475922+00:00 heroku router - - at=info method=HEAD path=/ host=pacific-forest-7999.herokuapp.com fwd="50.31.164.139/NX" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=25ms status=200 bytes=0
```

Comment: What is the error message you get when you post the form to your app? It looks like your app is not even receiving the request.

Comment: Its the enigmatic Heroku message "We're sorry, but something went wrong." on the page 'https://pacific-forest-7999.herokuapp.com/exams'.  But when i check the latest logentries i cant find anything about exam controller -so im confused as to what is happening.

Comment: Try to view your log live: heroku logs -t, and you can see what error message it's generating.

Comment: It looks like its an issue with CSRF for this request-thanks Yosep i think your suggestion identified my problem!-------- 2013-10-11T20:05:21.606079+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/exams" for 173.55.187.71 at 2013-10-11 20:05:21 +0000
2013-10-11T20:05:21.613549+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
2013-10-11T20:05:21.632666+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19ms     when i  add

Comment: actually i fixed the CSRF issue but app is still failing with same error message as before- see logs below- can anyone suggest a solution?    2013-10-11T20:26:05.195119+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/exams" for 173.55.187.71 at 2013-10-11 20:26:05 +0000
2013-10-11T20:26:05.201598+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ExamsController#create as HTML

2013-10-11T20:26:05.409087+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 207ms

2013-10-11T20:26:05.415225+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  permission denied for relation exams

Comment: Check this out. Your DB size limit may have been reached!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930996/pgerror-error-permission-denied-for-relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off CSFR check in your controller

```
def ExamsController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery :except => :create
```

Comment: actually i fixed the CSRF issue but app is still failing with same error message as before- see logs below- can anyone suggest a solution? 2013-10-11T20:26:05.195119+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/exams" for 173.55.187.71 at 2013-10-11 20:26:05 +0000 2013-10-11T20:26:05.201598+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ExamsController#create as HTML 2013-10-11T20:26:05.409087+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 207ms 2013-10-11T20:26:05.415225+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR: permission denied for relation exams

Comment: You are welcome. This kind of nonsense drives you crazy. Happy computing with Rails! It's some great fun stuff!