# Heroku pg:push gives psql permisison denied error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Whenever I type heroku pg:push to get my local database on heroku. I get the permission denied error. Any idea how I can solve it.

```
$  heroku pg:push mexico2019 HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COBALT_URL --app mexican
```

Error:

```
pg_dump: reading schemas
pg_dump: reading user-defined tables
pg_dump: SQL command failed
pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR:  permission denied for relation actions
pg_dump: The command was: LOCK TABLE public.actions IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
pg_dump: *** aborted because of error
pg_restore: [archiver] input file is too short (read 0, expected 5)
```

Database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  username: ram
  password: (password)
  database: mexico2019
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  username: postgres
  password: (password)
  database: meximexi_pro
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

### update:

```
                    List of relations
 Schema |             Name             |   Type   | Owner 
--------+------------------------------+----------+-------
 public | actions                      | table    | ram
 public | actions_id_seq               | sequence | ram
 public | admins                       | table    | ram
```

I tried

```
$ sudo su postgres
postgres=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mexico2019 TO ram;
GRANT
```

I just noticed when I type the password wrong it says 'psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "alain"', shouldn't it say user ram?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930996/pgerror-error-permission-denied-for-relation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using [PG Backups](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export).